# Magento Check out Problem

Tags: magento-1.9, php, onepage-checkout

During the check out process after filling the billing section, and trying to go to the Shipping section with the option "**Ship to this address**" I can not proceed, as I am able to go to the shipping section with the option "**Ship to different address**".

The console shows the following errors:

```
form.js:178 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null
    at klass.initialize (form.js:178)
    at klass (prototype.js:101)
    at (index):2112

form.js:178 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null
    at klass.initialize (form.js:178)
    at klass (prototype.js:101)
    at (index):2237
```

Comment: can you give site url?